# How to Retrieve Images Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of code, and I was wondering how to get my images to load on my site using jQuery.

```
$.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=New_Jersey&prop=text&format=json&callback=?', function(json) { 
    const text = json.parse.text['*'];
    const regex = /([-\w+\.\/]+(?:png|svg))/gmi;
    let m;
    while ((m = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
            picture = regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
        console.log(`Found match: ${m[1]}`);   
    }});
```

The images load on my console, but they won't load on my actual page. What can I do to display the images on my HTML page? Is that "m" variable what I need to use? I was told that my images would load on an absolute path, but I assume that these images are on a relative path, given it's coming from the Wikipedia API.

Comment: `$("containerElement").append('<img src="' + m[1] + '"/>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, just append an `img` element to an element on the DOM:

```js
$.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=New_Jersey&prop=text&format=json&callback=?', function(json) { 
  const text = json.parse.text['*'];
  const regex = /([-\w+\.\/]+(?:png|svg))/gmi;
  let m;
  while ((m = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
        picture = regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    $('#images').append('<img src="'+m[0]+'" />');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="images"></div>
```